# Terminology: Partition of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

I have a set of matrices $\{M_1, M_2,... M_n\}$ where each $M_k(i,j) = 0$ or $1$ such that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n M_i  = \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 1 & \dots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \\
    1 &        & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}$$

If $M_k(i,j) = 1$ then $M_{k'}(i,j) = 0$ for all $k'\neq k$.

Thus the set $\{M_1, M_2,... M_n\}$ "partitions" the all ones matrix in some way. What is the correct terminology for this?

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for this. The set of all positions in the matrix is partitioned by the $M_i$ so when writing about this configuration it would be reasonable to define "partition" this way in this context. Your readers would be comfortable with that.